# Remove inverted commas from href javascript

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Hi I have href which I am dynamically cereated but i don't want inverted commas in it but its coming with inverted commas how to remove kindly help

**Here is my code:**

```
$('#txtFrameClinChn').html("&lt;iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid'" + sessionStorage.LoggedInOrganizationHeadOrganizationID + "' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='1000'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;");
```

**Which generate this href :**

```
<iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid='717c043d-126f-4f57-910b-247a83d58801' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='1000'></iframe>
```

I do not want  this `clhid='717c043d-126f-4f57-910b-247a83d58801'` instead I want 
`clhid=717c043d-126f-4f57-910b-247a83d58801`.

Comment: If you don't want that "inverted comma" (a.k.a. apostrophe or single quote), *then why are you putting it in the first place?* (It also looks like your first code snippet is missing an equal sign, but that may just be a typo.)

Comment: if i am not giving it, it is not working,it is treating it as string the + sign also coming under string

Comment: *`"&lt;iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid'"`* <- there, right before the double quote.

Comment: yes if i am giving it simply it is not working

Comment: yes i Have tried but it is not working

Comment: yes but the hint i got from it i modified it,and I appreciate your answer thanks for help ,I upvoted you for that

Answer (score 0):

So why do you use a comma next to "Home.aspx?clhid"

> html(src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid      **'**      " + sessionStorage.LoggedInOrganizationHeadOrganizationID + "**'**

**EDIT:** If you need the inverted commas you can escape them: \'

Comment: we can't use \ before Single quotes as its a link so \ will be treated as a part of link

Comment: Is it not escaped? How about &quot;

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quote `'` that should be equal `=` instead just after `Home.aspx?clhid`, replace it and the code will be :

```
$('#txtFrameClinChn').html("&lt;iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20
     Booking/Home.aspx?clhid=" + sessionStorage.LoggedInOrganizationHeadOrganizationID + "'
     frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='1000'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;");
```

**Output :**

```
<iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid=eeee'
    frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='1000'></iframe>
```

**NOTE :** I think `Home.aspx?clhid` should be `Home.aspx?child` instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#txtFrameClinChn').html("&lt;iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid=" + sessionStorage.LoggedInOrganizationHeadOrganizationID + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="1000" &gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;');
```

Try this,it may help.